# VS2008 plugins to add regexp replace to the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, plugins

I'm looking for a way to make the search/replace function of VS IDE regex-aware, like regex replace in Notepad++. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the "+" sign to the left of "Find Options", and click the check box next to "Use", and select "Regular Expressions" from the drop down list.

Edit:

[image: Picture of Find and Replace Dialog]

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to VS2008 so I missed it.